# Convert signed formatted bytes to unsigned bytes

Tags: c#, byte, unsigned, signed

How can I convert byte data stored as if they were signed bytes to unsigned bytes?

The reason being is because I have some old sound files (from an Amiga), but they were stored in IFF 8SVX which used signed bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
public void convertSignedToUnsignedBytes(byte[] b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++) {
        if (b[i] >= 128) b[i] -= 128;
        else b[i] += 128;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting with `sbyte[] signedBytes` then try this:

```
byte[] unsignedBytes = signedBytes.Select(sb => (byte)sb).ToArray();
```

Comment: Nope, we're starting with byte[], but the numbers therein are 'pretending' to be signed bytes. See my answer below...